# why my Mileage tracker for a runner keeps returning zeros

Tags: java

Given the MileageTrackerNode class, complete main() in the MileageTrackerLinkedList class to insert nodes into a linked list (using the insertAfter() method). The first user-input value is the number of nodes in the linked list. Use the printNodeData() method to print the entire linked list. DO NOT print the dummy head node.

Ex. If the input is:

3
2.2
7/2/18
3.2
7/7/18
4.5
7/16/18
the output is:

2.2, 7/2/18
3.2, 7/7/18
4.5, 7/16/18

for some reason, I keep getting:
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,

// code

MileageTrackerNode.java

```
public class MileageTrackerNode {
   private double miles;         // Node data                                                         
   private String date;          // Node data
   private MileageTrackerNode nextNodeRef; // Reference to the next node                              

   public MileageTrackerNode() {
      miles = 0.0;
      date = "";
      nextNodeRef = null;
   }

   // Constructor                                                                                     
   public MileageTrackerNode(double milesInit, String dateInit) {
      this.miles = milesInit;
      this.date = dateInit;
      this.nextNodeRef = null;
   }

   // Constructor                                                                                     
   public MileageTrackerNode(double milesInit, String dateInit, MileageTrackerNode nextLoc) {
      this.miles = milesInit;
      this.date = dateInit;
      this.nextNodeRef = nextLoc;
   }

   /* Insert node after this node.                                                                    
   Before: this -- next                                                                               
   After:  this -- node -- next                                                                       
   */
   public void insertAfter(MileageTrackerNode nodeLoc) {
      MileageTrackerNode tmpNext;

      tmpNext = this.nextNodeRef;
      this.nextNodeRef = nodeLoc;
      nodeLoc.nextNodeRef = tmpNext;
   }

   // Get location pointed by nextNodeRef                                                             
   public MileageTrackerNode getNext() {
      return this.nextNodeRef;
   }

   public void printNodeData() {
      System.out.println(this.miles + ", " + this.date);
   }
}
```

MileageTrackerLinkedList.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MileageTrackerLinkedList {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      

      // References for MileageTrackerNode objects
      MileageTrackerNode headNode;                                           
      MileageTrackerNode currNode;
      MileageTrackerNode lastNode;

      double miles;
      String date;
      int i;
      int numNodes;

      // Front of nodes list                                                                         
      headNode = new MileageTrackerNode();
      lastNode = headNode;

      // TODO: Scan the number of nodes
      numNodes = scnr.nextInt();

      
      
         
      // TODO: For the scanned number of nodes, scan
      //       in data and insert into the linked list
      for (i = 0; i < numNodes; ++i) {
         miles = scnr.nextDouble();
         date = scnr.next();
         currNode = new MileageTrackerNode(miles, date);         
         lastNode.insertAfter(currNode);
         lastNode = currNode;
      }
            

      // TODO: Call the printNodeData() method 
      //       to print the entire linked list
      for (i = 0; i < numNodes; ++i) {
         headNode.printNodeData();
         headNode.getNext();
      }
            
   }
}
```

Comment: What values does `headNode` take as you loop?

Comment: it does not take any value because it is set, by the instructions, as a new object for `MIleageTrackerNode()`.

Comment: As your `for` loop executes, printing out your nodes, you print the value of the node referred to by `headNode` each time. Does `headNode` change to traverse your list during the loop? (This is a rhetorical question to prompt you to look at the part of your code which is causing your problem)